# How to import a module once I have installed the module on a virtual environment - TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtual-environment

I am very new to this virtual environment concept. So if you could also explain that, it would be great.

Anyways, I am using Anaconda3. Here are the steps that I took to try to use TensorFlow.

1. From "base" anaconda I tried to install, which gave me the below error.

```
(base) C:\Users\ikim1>conda create -n tf tensorflow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
```

FYI, the Environment -> base tab on Anaconda3 did not show TensorFlow - seems like some people were lucky that their Anaconda3 just came with TensowFlow Module...

2. After reading some documentation, I realized that using virtual environment can solve the issue. And then after using "tf" as a virtual environment name, I was able to install TensorFlow.

After the install, I ran this code

```
conda activate tf
```

to activate the environment.

3. On Spyder, I checked if TensorFlow would import with the below code

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

which gives me this error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Thus my question is do I need to change directory so that Python knows where it needs to import the module from? So do I need to write a code like below in Spyder?

```
cd "my virtual environment" (not sure what the code would be)
import tensorflow as tf
```

Or did I just make some mistake installing it?

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following command to see if Tensorflow is installed. It will either state that the package is not installed or display a bunch of information about it.

```
pip show tensorflow
```

If the Tensorflow package is not already installed, please try installing it in the environment where you are working with the following commands before attempting to import tensorflow.

```
# activate the environment
conda activate tf
# install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
```